# Sharing my database layer with both play and akka-http projects

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka-http

I have a play app that is using play-slick (postgresql)
I want to create another akka-http application that will be a sbt multi-project setup with the following:

1. play application
2. akka http
3. shared db library that both play and akka http will use

My play app is using play-slick, and my DAO/table classes look like this:

```
@Singleton
class AccountDAO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  private val accounts = TableQuery[AccountsTable]

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = ....
}
```

Now I am confused how I would use this same object in my akka-http project because it will not be using the play-slick library, 
and the DatabaseConfigProvider seems to be from the play-slick library.

I looked at an akka-http template that I like but they are wiring up slick differently:

```
class DatabaseService(jdbcUrl: String, dbUser: String, dbPassword: String) {
  private val hikariConfig = new HikariConfig()
  hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl)
  hikariConfig.setUsername(dbUser)
  hikariConfig.setPassword(dbPassword)

  private val dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)

  val driver = slick.driver.PostgresDriver
  import driver.api._
  val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource)
  db.createSession()
}
```

[github Reference](https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest/blob/master/src/main/scala/me/archdev/restapi/utils/DatabaseService.scala)

So they have this DatabaseService class that they pass as a parameter into their DAO/Service layer like: https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest/blob/master/src/main/scala/me/archdev/restapi/services/UsersService.scala#L9

And their tables are traits like the [UserEntityTable](https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest/blob/master/src/main/scala/me/archdev/restapi/models/db/UserEntityTable.scala)

Is it possible to change my code in a way that I can re-use my database layer in both the play and akka-http projects?